# How to replicate conversion of string to Binary in SQL sever in Snowflake

Tags: sql-server, encryption, binary, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I encrypted some data in SQL server and it produced a result similar to `0x4E616D65`
The goal is to load the encrypted data into Snowflake but I seem to be getting errors due to the `0x` prefix of the binary.
With SQL server I am  able to convert Binary to Varchar and the converted Varchar back to binary and get accurate results

```
--Convert Binary to String
SELECT CONVERT(Varchar(8000), 0x4E616d65, 2) AS [string_result];

Result = 4E616d65

--convert string to binary
SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(4), '4E616D65', 2) AS [binary_result];
Result =  0x4E616d65
```

For loading into SNowflake, I have decided to convert the binary to varchar, producing this result `4E616d65` and load into Snowflake, but how do I get this binary output in snowflake  `Result =  0x4E616d65`
I tried casting to Binary, Using To_binary but the functions do not add the 0x prefix

Comment: The queries you posted are SQL server only. Please post your Snowflake queries as well so we can better understand what you're trying do to.